# C - sorted linked list with words and frequencies

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, word-frequency

I'm having some issues finalizing my code for my programming course (I'm an absolute beginner in C). The aim is to read words from standard input (runfile < input.c), count their frequencies, and sort the list alphabetically (capitalized words first), example output:

[Image Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZaec.png)

I found pieces of codes here on Stack, which I adapted, and so far it produces the output with words and their frequencies. However, I can't figure out how to get the list sorted as in the sample above. Our teacher suggests, that if a new word is found, it should be inserted sorted straight away into the linked list, he gave us following code sample (it is an excerpt from [this program](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zmfivg0igd8mk91/intList1.c)):

```
void addSorted(link *n, int x) {
  if (*n == NULL || x < (*n)->data) {
    *n = cons(x, *n);
  } else {
    addSorted(&((*n)->next), x);
  }
}
```

As far as I understand it, 'link *n' should be the pointer to the next node, 'data' is holding integers in that case, and 'cons' should be a function within this code to construct a new node or link, not sure about 'int x', my guess it's the current integer for comparison. 
As I said, I'm having trouble adapting this last bit into my code. I tried to adapt my addWord() function, but it doesn't work out for me.
Below you find the working code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//=============== STRUCTURE ==================
typedef struct word {
    char *mywords;              // list node with word pointer 
    int freq;                   // Frequency count
    struct word *pNext;         // Pointer to next node in linked list 
    } Word;

//======= INITIATION OF FUNCTIONS ===========
int readWord(char *temp_word, int temp_size);   // Given function to get words
void addWord(char *pWord);                      // Adds a word to the list or updates exisiting word
void printmywords(Word *pListNodes);            // Output list of words and frequencies
Word* construct(char *word);                    // Constructs list nodes

//============GLOBAL VARIABLES================
Word *pFirst = NULL;                  // Pointer to first node in linked list

//================ MAIN ======================    
int main () {

    char temp_word[32]; // temporary buffer to hold words
    int size = 10000;

    Word *pNode = NULL; // pointer to word counter

    while (readWord(temp_word, size)) { // Read all words from standard input

        addWord(temp_word); // Add word to list
    }

    // List the words and their counts
    pNode = pFirst;
    while(pNode != NULL)
    {
        printmywords(pNode);
        pNode = pNode->pNext;
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Free the allocated  memory
    pNode = pFirst;
    while(pNode != NULL)
    {
        free(pNode->mywords);        
        pFirst = pNode;           
        pNode = pNode->pNext;  
        free(pFirst);                  
    }
     return 0;
}

//================ FUNCTIONS =================

void printmywords(Word *pListNodes)
{
    printf("\n%-20s   %5d", pListNodes->mywords,pListNodes->freq); // output word and frequency
}

void addWord(char *word)
{
  Word *pNode = NULL;
  Word *pLast = NULL;

  if(pFirst == NULL)
  {
    pFirst = construct(word);
    return;
  }

  // Update frequency, if word in list
  pNode = pFirst;
  while(pNode != NULL)
  {
    if(strcmp(word, pNode->mywords) == 0)
    {
      ++pNode->freq;
      return;
    }
    pLast = pNode;            
    pNode = pNode->pNext;  
  }

  // Add new word, if not in list
  pLast->pNext = construct(word);
}

Word* construct(char *word)
{
  Word *pNode = NULL;
  pNode = (Word*)malloc(sizeof(Word));
  pNode->mywords = (char*)malloc(strlen(word)+1);
  strcpy(pNode->mywords, word);
  pNode->freq = 1;
  pNode->pNext = NULL;
  return pNode;
}

int readWord(char *temp_word, int temp_size) {
    char *p = temp_word;
    char c;

    // skip all non-word characters
    do {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF) 
            return 0;
        } while (!isalpha(c));

    // read word chars
    do {
        if (p - temp_word < temp_size - 1)
        *p++ = c;
        c = getchar();
        } while (isalpha(c));

        // finalize word
        *p = '\0';
        return 1;
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, the "code sample" is complete gibberish. It's not even very good pseudo-code. If you want to sort a datum relative to other data, you have to have a way to compare them. Once you have that, for a linked list, you either insert the new node between 2 nodes, or after the last one.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the sample code, I added more explanation and a link to the source code, I hope that clarifies that bit. That sample program compares integers to each other, when sorting them. I guess it's a bit easier.
In my case I'm wondering if I should use something like strcmp()?

Comment: Hey, look at that - it's not gibberish any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, try these two functions:

```
Word *cons(char *word, Word *next) {
  Word *result = construct(word);
  if (result) {
    result->pNext = next;
  }
  else {
    printf("Out of memory in cons\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  return result;
}

void addSorted(Word **nodeRef, char *word) {
  Word *node = *nodeRef;

  /* strcmp will do a binary comparison, which suits your purpose
     because you want capitalized words before lower-case; the order
     of the arguments is important - <0 means the first argument should
     come before the second argument. */

  if ((node == NULL) || (strcmp(word, node->mywords) < 0)) {
    *nodeRef = cons(word, node);
  }
  else if (strcmp(word, node->mywords) == 0) {
    ++node->freq;
  }
  else {
    /* there's not really any point to using recursion on a linked
       list, except for the fact that it's really easy to use recursion
       on a linked list. On a vary large list, iteration would most likely
       be faster; however, professors really like to show how clever they
       are, so you're better off using it anyway. */

    addSorted(&node->pNext, word);
  }
}
```

A couple of other points:

```
char temp_word[32]; // temporary buffer to hold words
int size = 10000;
```

You've got a 31 character buffer, but you're telling your `readWord` function that it is 10K characters?

Also, don't cast the return value from `malloc()`.

Comment: Thanks for that! Couldn't use them as they were, but they definitely contain some points I was missing in my code. Sufficient enough to rewrite my construct() and addWord() function. Works now as it should!
Regarding the buffer and size, can't explain it exactly, it was suggested to set a maximum buffer for each word and a max size for the list, so the program would not run for ages. If found that in several codes working with words and linked lists, so I was just reusing this.